# Craft 3: When querying for Matrix blocks in a plugin, how do you sort by a custom field?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, craft3

My goal is to order an element query of Matrix blocks by a custom field. Any thoughts?

```
namespace modules\mymodule\services;

use Craft;
use yii\base\Component;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;

class MyService extends Component
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $blocks = MatrixBlock::find()
            ->type('myBlockType')
            ->orderBy(???)
            ->all();
    }
}
```

**Edit to show working Example**

(This is showing how I used this to sort by a custom date field)

```
$blocks = MatrixBlock::find()
    ->type('blockType')
    ->fieldId($fieldId)
    ->where(['>', 'content.field_blockType_fieldHandle', new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()')])
    ->orderBy(['content.field_blockType_fieldHandle' => SORT_ASC])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
->orderBy('fieldHandle')
```

or

```
->orderBy(['fieldHandle' => SORT_DESC])
```

But you have to make sure the field is sortable, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When you say "sortable" could you elaborate? For example, could I sort on a date time field? 

I've tried this exact code and I can get an error saying the field handle doesn't exist and in the query it doesn't look like craft is joining on the actual content table.

Comment: Craft won't join the content table in MatrixQueries since Matrix blocks have their custom content tables. You'll have to use the exact column name `$columnName = Craft::$app->getContent()->contentTable . '.' . Craft::$app->getContent()->fieldColumnPrefix . $field->handle;` Only textual fields are sortable.. You can't sort relation fields or something like these

Comment: Oh, this looks like it's for an entry. What about a Matrix?

Comment: If I put `->orderBy('craft_matrixcontent_mymatrixfield.field_blockType_fieldName')` I get a DB exception

Comment: Sry for the late reply. Did you specify a valid `fieldId` in your query? Otherwise it won't join the correct table and you'll have to do it on your own (I throught that was obvious sorry)

Comment: Not obvious to a dolt like me ;-) Thanks that was it!

Comment: When you specify the field id, craft will select the fields with `as fieldHandle` so you don't need to specify the correct database column name. That is only important when you want to join the table on your own. Sry again^^ glad you got it working